# Dual Wielding and Rogue Poisons

Tags: rift

Two of the roles in Rift, Warrior and Rogue, have the ability to dual-wield. Certain "souls" (effectively classes) gain buffs that grant on-hit effects to weapon attacks.

For instance -- the Assassin Soul offers poisons (up to two at a time, even) while the Rift Blade Soul offers the StormBlade buff (among others).

In the case of the rogue -- do your two poisons represent "off-hand" and "main-hand", or are both weapons benefiting from both poisons?

In the case of the warrior -- does the Stormblade buff apply to your off-hand weapon when you dual-wield, or does the buff only ever affect the main hand weapon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not used to the warrior skills but the rogue ones. Skill like "Lethal Poison" or "Leeching Poison" are buffs of the character and not buffs of the weapons. So both weapons "benefit" from the both poison buffs.

Currently it's unclear if you increase the chance the poison effect get applied on the mob if your on dual wield; probable not.

Comment: One way to show that the poisons affect the character and not the weapon is that ranged attacks will trigger weapon enchantments as well.